# How to search for substring in one of two fields of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns: `id`, `first`, and `last`.

I'd like to find all records where 'SAM' is in either the first or last field.

I'm not an expert with MySQL, but it seems to me that one field could be queried using the `LIKE` operator.

How can I use `LIKE` in a query to get data from both columns at the same time?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM `employees` 
WHERE 'first' like 'SAM' OR 'last' like 'SAM'
```

But I get the message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to figure out why you are getting a syntax error, but one problem with your query is that by putting single quotes around your column name causes it to be treated like a string literal instead of a column name.

What I mean by that is instead of comparing the value in the `first` column with the string 'SAM', it's comparing two strings, 'first' and 'SAM' which are different. This query would return no results.

In addition, this will only work if the first or last name is equal to sam. To check for those characters as a substring at any point, I would add wildcards at the front and back of the strings.

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM employees
WHERE first LIKE '%SAM%' OR last LIKE '%SAM%'
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d3f8/1) to show how it works.

Comment: Not a problem. Do you have the entire query you tried in the beginning? It's possible the syntax is as a result of something that wasn't copied. Maybe you had a misspelt word, or missing keyword. Either way, as long as you've got it working now, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any syntax error in the query you posted. What you have is really close.

Your query isn't comparing the contents of the columns; it's comparing string literals, because of the single quotes, those are strings, not column references.

The `LIKE` comparison is equivalent to an equality comparison, since the there aren't any wildcard characters in the string on the right side. The `'%'` character is a wildcard that will match any number of characters.

To return rows where either of the columns `first` or `last` contain the string "SAM", you could do something like this:

```
SELECT e.id FROM employees e WHERE e.first LIKE '%SAM%' OR e.last LIKE '%SAM%'
```

That query would match any of these example rows:

```
id  first      last
--  ---------  -------
 2  Flotsam   
 3  Samson 
 5  Sesame 
 7  Yosemite   Sam
```

Comment: *I don't see any syntax error in the query you posted* The column names are quoted.

Comment: @Juergend the column names being quoted is not a syntax error. Sure, it is the problem, but there's no cause for MySQL to reject that.

Comment: @juergen d: The single quotes around column names is *not* the cause the "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" error reported by OP; in the OP query, those are string literals. The SQL *syntax* is actually valid, even though it doesn't perform the operation that OP  wants.